# Remove Null Values from MYSQL during select

Tags: php, mysql

I have a survey form which records multiple responses in a MYSQL table and each member can refer to a different member in a different response or choose not to which will then be set as NULL as the table below.

```
membername-----referralto
Mike  -------- NULL
Ali  --------  NULL 
Mike  -------  Jack  
Ali  --------  Jill
```

I want the names of members and who the referrals were for. So here's what i tried;

```
SELECT membername, referralto 
FROM responses
```

This query returns me the NULL Values in the `referralto` fields as well. Is there a way i can filter out the NULL Values?
I even tried this as well but it didn't work.

```
SELECT membername, NULLIF( referralto, '' )  AS member 
FROM responses
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried just adding "where referralto is not null"?

```
SELECT membername, NULLIF( referralto, '' )  AS member 
FROM responses
WHERE referralto IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: @Ahmadspikes: Is it possible you are storing a string 'NULL' instead of a real NULL?

Comment: Ahh, Yes. That did the problem! Thank you. I just tried your query and it worked. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by`

```
SELECT membername,referralto  AS member 
FROM responses
GROUP BY membername
```

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY, was my best solution on my case.

Comment: This is already one of the answers on this question, plus it would be better with a code snippet

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34178677)